# What is number of partitions after DynamoDB restore?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

There is [back-up and restore](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/backup-restore/) feature for DynamoDB. [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/backuprestore_HowItWorks.html) says that when you restore table read and write capacity will remain same as source table when you did back-up.

> The destination table is set with the same provisioned read capacity
>   units and write capacity units as the source table, as recorded at the
>   time the backup was requested.

But what is total number of partitions for destination table in this case? Your original source table can have lot of partitions with small Read and Write capacity. How is this going to be reflected?

Answer (score 0):

An interesting side effect of this is that you can use it to reduce your partition count.  For instance if you did a rapid table load with a high high WCU count and now need to reduce the partition count to improve performance.  You can reduce your WCR & RCU levels to what you need, do the Backup and then Restore it.  This will reset your partition count.